# JSON multilined images code

Tags: json

I need to store a multi-lined img src code in json to use in jquery later, but there is something wrong with a syntax. So if I store just one line like that

```
{
        "captionthree":

        "<img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/3dmax.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"3D Stuio Max\">"

}
```

it works.

But if I put multiple lines it doesn't:

```
{
        "captionthree":

        "<img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/3dmax.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"3D Stuio Max\">
        <img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/zbrush.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"ZBrush\">
        <img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/topogun.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"Topogun\">
        <img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/vray.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"V-Ray\">
        <img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/mari.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"MARI Foundry\">
        <img class=\"smallicon\" src=\"logos/photoshop.png\" height=\"20px\" width=\"20px\" title=\"Adobe Photoshop\">",

}
```

And here is jquery line I'm inserting it into:

```
$('#captionthree').html(database[globalswitchNumber].captionthree);
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is there an error on your console?

Comment: no there are no errors, I mean that json multilined  code doesn't go through as multilined code, but if I just use one line - it works

Comment: Try putting all the images in one line. Remove the new line.

Comment: It worked. You can add it as an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the new line before each image tag. Because of the new lines it is not handled as one string.